# Having an issue with scenes in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, webstorm, wampserver, phaser-framework

I have a project with two scenes, the scenes should be showing some text on the canvas but nothing happens. All I get is a black canvas.

game.js:

```
window.onload = function(){

  var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000,
    scene: [Scene1, Scene2]
  }

  var game = new Phaser.Game();
}
```

Scene1.js

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super("bootGame");
    }

    create() {
        this.add.text(20, 30, "Loading game...");
        this.scene.start("playGame");
    }
}
```

Scene2.js

```
class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor() {
        super("playGame");
    }

    create(){
        this.add.text(20, 20, "Playing game", {font: "25px Arial", fill: "yellow"});
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Phaser Game</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scene1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scene2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[console feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09qio.png)

Comment: in your question you need to post minimum code for reproducing the error

Comment: At least one of your problems is that you need to actually pass in the config. Like `var game = new Phaser.Game(config);` You're just using the default constructor in your example and not passing in your scenes

Answer (score 0):

From what you've sent it seems the main issue is that you didn't pass `config` into your instance of `Phaser.Game` in `game.js`.